# Standalone (syntactically or in separate file) inner classes in Java?

Tags: java, module, inner-classes

Are there any ways to define standalone inner classes in Java?

NB: I need not "partial" classes as in C#, I need full classes, but inner.

Are there any plans to introduce such syntax in future Javas?

```
package tests.java;

public class Try_InnerClassStandalone_01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer O1 = new Outer(12);
        Outer O2 = new Outer(13);

        Outer.Inner i1 = O1.new Inner();
        System.out.println(i1.getData());

        InnerExt i2 = O1.new InnerExt();
        System.out.println(i2.getData());

    }
}

class Outer {

    class Inner {
        int getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public int data;

    public Outer(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class InnerExt extends Outer.Inner {

}
```

**UPDATE**

I know what is the difference between static and non-static inner classes. And I want to utilize the advantages and avoid disadvantages.

Advantage is the ability to refer `Outer.this` implicitly (shorter code).

Disadvantage is the necessity to put inner class into the boundaries of outer class definition (no modularity).

Comment: Why? Apparently no difference between `i1` and `i2`. In both cases outer instance is provided during construction.

Comment: I want no static, I need inner and non-static. I require hidden outer class instance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The most important reason to do this is probably to tie an instance of an inner class to an instance of the outer one. If an instance of class A created in the context of an instance of class B can only be used correctly in that same context, then A should logically be an inner class of B. Convenient access to B's fields and methods is a nice side benefit. I'm currently writing a small simulation; logically, a bunch of classes should be inner classes, but there's way too much code to want to shove it all in one file. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Outer {
    static class Inner {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Instances of a non-static inner class have an implicit reference to an instance of their enclosing class. If you want what I suspect what you mean with a "stand-alone inner class", you should make the inner class `static`.

Comment: Yes, instances of "non-static inner class have an implicit reference to an instance of their enclosing class". This is what I want. So, your suggestion to use static classes does not match.

Comment: It is important to realize that `static` has no other implication, than being independent to the outer class (no `Outer.this`).

Comment: What do you mean with a "stand-alone inner class"?

Comment: Then I think that what you want is not possible; you cannot have a non-static inner class defined outside its enclosing class.

Comment: @Jesper ok, but do they plan to add this possibility in future Javas? Without it the concept of inner classes looks incomplete.

Comment: I've never heard of plans to include this feature in a future version of Java, so I wouldn't count on this being included anytime soon. Note that non-static inner classes can directly access member variables of the enclosing class. That would look weird if the inner class was in a separate source file.

Comment: @Jesper Inner class is by definition non-static. Nested != Inner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this

```
class InnerExt extends Outer.Inner {

}
```

Because `Inner` is only relevant in the context of an `Outer` instance. You cannot extend it outside the context of `Outer`. Like you could do

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {

    }
    class InnerExt extends Inner {

    }
}
```

Otherwise you need to make `Inner` a `static` class. You could then extend it in the scope of its visibility.